# Replicate/Sync Production database with Development database (no Master/Slave)

Tags: mysql, replication

I currently use ClearDB MySQL DaaS for my production database, and a local MySQL database on my dev server for development. I need to have the production database replicated/copied/synced to the dev database so the data my dev app is working with is the same as the production data.

Because ClearDB is a DaaS implementation, I have no ability to set up and sort of master slave replication. I am struggling to find the best solution to keep my dev database either

A) Constantly in sync with my production database
or
B) Synced once a day either manually or automatically

At the moment I am doing a complete dump of the production, and inserting in to my dev database. This is already quite time consuming, but as the production database grows, this will not be an option very soon.

Any suggestions of a way to accomplish either A or B above without a master slave configuration.